# Server Returning Internal Error after Centos/PHP upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

I need some guidance to fix my server. I have a VPS with CentOS, Apache, Linux, PHP and plesk.

Yesterday, I made an update using yum of PHP 5.1.6 to 5.3.8 and CentOS. Updated php.ini and restarted services.but something went wrong since server is returning a 500 internal server error to all sites since then.

My apache log don't show any activity when trying to load sites, the log only displays activity when server is restarted and no errors are shown.

I am able to run .php files from ssh and php -v returns version 5.3.8

Where should I be looking at ? what may be missing?

Comment: Can you run a phpinfo() script without getting error 500?

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look is in your error logs.  Both the Apache error log (usually in /var/log/httpd/error.log on CentOS) and the PHP error log (not configured by default but look for the `error_log` line in your php.ini).

Once you find the error message, add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately as i said before error log does not tell me anything useful

Comment: If there's a 500 response code in your Apache access log and nothing in your Apache error log then it would seem to be a PHP error.  What do you see in your PHP error log?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some sites break when upgrading from php5.2 to php5.3. Can you upgrade to just php5.2? Do you have all the same modules installed after the upgrade?